Is there a closed form for the quadratic Euler Mascheroni Constant?
Short Version:
I am interested in computing (as a closed form) the limit if it does exist:
$$ \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \left[\sum_{a^2+b^2 \le k^2; (a,b) \ne 0} \frac{1}{a^2+b^2}  - 2\pi\ln(k)  \right] $$
And if it does not exist but that difference happens to limit to a periodic function then I am interested instead in computing its average value that is:
$$ \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \text{Average}_{m \in [1,k]} \left[\sum_{a^2+b^2 \le m^2; (a,b) \ne 0} \frac{1}{a^2+b^2}  - 2\pi\ln(m)  \right] $$
If both of these assumptions are wrong then a proof of why they are wrong would also be an accepted answer.
Setup:
The following sum is known to diverge.
$$\sum_{(a,b) \in \mathbb{Z}^2; (a,b) \ne (0,0)} \frac{1}{a^2+b^2} $$
It can be viewed as a 2-dimensional variation of the divergent harmonic sum
$$\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}; n   \ne 0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n} $$
The harmonic series has a nice expansion of the form
$$ \sum_{|n| \le k; n \ne 0, }^{} \frac{1}{n} = 2\ln(k) + 2\gamma + O \left( \frac{1}{n} \right)  $$
I was looking to compute the same for the quadratic sum. After experimentally tinkering with Desmos here:
It really does appear that
$$ \sum_{a^2+b^2 \le k^2; (a,b) \ne 0} \frac{1}{a^2+b^2}  = 2\pi \ln(k) + \text{some periodic function} + O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) $$
But I have no proof of this at this time. Now that periodic function seems to have an average value of around 2.5 (if you play with the desmos link)

Question:
Can that 2.5ish constant be expressed as a closed form with any known constants? There are a ton of constants we have now in the 21st century that Euler didn't have when he invented his $\gamma$.  I would be hopeful that a closed form for something this "simple-looking" (its just replacing the harmonic series with a quadratic one instead) should exist.
A start might be to be very optimistic and just assume that
$$ \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \left[\sum_{a^2+b^2 \le k^2; (a,b) \ne 0}\frac{1}{a^2+b^2}  - 2\pi\ln(k)  \right] $$
Exists and is a constant (i.e. the periodic looking function limits to a constant) much like Euler did back in his day. If this could be a transformed into a nice integral some cleo-like magic might be able to resolve it in terms of known things.
Some Ideas:
The usual generalization of Euler Mascheroni constant are the Stieltjes Constants but they involve adding logarithmic weights to the harmonic series as opposed to replacing the harmonic series with a divergence quadratic series.
Also a closely related fact is that individual slices of this divergent sum do converge. For example famously $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$. This is a 1-D slice of our divergent 2-D sum (with angle 0). I believe for any rational angle the corresponding sum converges and I would really not be surprised if they all had closed forms nicely related to the Riemann zeta function.

You may find https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/851302/how-to-prove-sum-m-1-infty-sum-n-1-infty-frac1m2n2-infty interesting. Also, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/149138/convergence-of-multiple-series-sum-frac1n2m2 and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1541788/computing-sum-frac1m2n2

Just to clarify : Do you want to compute $\gamma^2$ numerically WITHOUT before computing $\gamma$ ?

If it helps I believe that $\sum^{N}_{m,n=1} \frac{1}{m^2+n^2}$ ~ $\frac{\pi}{2}ln(N)-\frac{\pi^2}{12}$ but I have yet to be able to find a version of the argument that awnsers your exact question.

@Peter I could improve the question. Let’s call the constant I want to compute $\gamma_2$. I want to compute some kind of closed form for $\gamma_2$ in terms of other known constants and functions. Numerically I know $\gamma_2$ already is around 2.5

Let $A_n = \sum^{N}{a,b=1} \frac1{a^2+b^2} -\frac \pi 2\ln n$ be @AidanR.S. sequence , $P_n = \sum{a,b > 0; a^2+b^2 \le n} \frac1{a^2+b^2}- \frac \pi 2\ln n$ and $R_n = \sum_{a=1}^n \frac 1{n^2}$. Now,  $P_n$ satisfies $$A_{n/2} \le P_n \le A_n$$ Thus if Aidan R.S. is correct that $A_n \to \frac{\pi^2}{12}$, then $P_n \to \frac{\pi^2}{12}$ also. If we change the sum in $P_n$ to require $a\ne 0, b\ne 0$ instead of $> 0$, the original sum is multiplied by $4$. So we need to multiply the log term by $4$ as well.

Also we can add in $4R_n$ to get $$Q_n = \sum_{a^2+b^2 \le n,(a,b) \ne (0.0)} \frac1{a^2+b^2}- 2\pi\ln n \to 4\frac{\pi^2}{12} + 4\frac{\pi^2}6 = \pi^2$$ Your sequence is $Q_{k^2} +2\pi \ln k$. As a subsequence of $Q_n$, $Q_k^2$ converges to the same limit, so if Aidan R.S. is correct, you have the wrong coefficient to the log term for convergence (or vice versa if you are correct - I haven't looked into either.)

@PaulSinclair the sum is only asymtotically equal, and prety certain it is I wrote a proof but Im not gonna put it here as it doesnt actually awnser the question, the sequence of Q would monotonically increase to $\pi^{2}$.

Did you find anything useful in the links I posted, Sidharth?

Yes actually! they resulted in me asking another question. I’m going to try to digest one of the more elaborate proofs over the weekend since it might allow me to resolve:  this

Using this answer, it's not hard to show that the limit equals
$$
L=\color{blue}{\pi\big(2\gamma-\ln\pi+4\ln\Gamma(3/4)\big)}\approx 2.584981759579253217+
$$
Indeed, we have $L=\lim\limits_{N\to\infty}4\left(A_N+\frac{\pi^2}6-\frac{\pi}2\ln N\right)$, where
$$
A_N=\sum_{\substack{m,n\geqslant 1\\m^2+n^2\leqslant N^2}}\frac1{m^2+n^2},\qquad B_N=\sum_{1\leqslant m,n\leqslant N}\frac1{m^2+n^2}.
$$
Viewing $B_N-A_N$ as a "Riemann sum", we see that
\begin{align*}
\lim_{N\to\infty}(B_N-A_N)&=\iint\limits_{\substack{0\leqslant x,y\leqslant 1\\x^2+y^2\geqslant 1}}\frac{dx\,dy}{x^2+y^2}=2\iint\limits_{\substack{0\leqslant\phi\leqslant\pi/4\\r\cos\phi\leqslant 1\leqslant r}}\frac{r\,dr\,d\phi}{r^2}
\\&=-2\int_0^{\pi/4}\ln\cos\phi\,d\phi=\frac\pi2\ln2-G
\end{align*}
(using polar coordinates; here $G$ is Catalan's constant).
Finally, the asymptotics of $B_N$ (as $N\to\infty$) is obtained in the linked answer.

I wonder if $\frac{\pi^{1/4}}{\Gamma(3/4)}=\sum\limits_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}e^{-\pi n^2}$ has anything to do with it ;)

2.584981759579253217... is known as Sierpiński's constant (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpi%C5%84ski%27s_constant and https://oeis.org/A062089), but I frankly haven't ever seen it in this context (2D lattice sum).

I found two references:
J. A. Scott, Euler limits for some doubly-infinite series, Math. Gazette 85 (2001) 504–507;
J. A. Scott, A double integral, a rectangular hyperbola and the harmonic mean, Math. Gazette 87 (2003) 532–534;
confirming metamorphy's formula.

@S.Finch Note that $$
\sum\limits_{\substack{a^2  + b^2  \le k^2 \ (a,b) \ne (0,0)}} {\frac{1}{{a^2  + b^2 }}}  = \sum\limits_{j = 1}^{k^2 } {\sum\limits_{a^2  + b^2  = j} {\frac{1}{j}} }  = \sum\limits_{j = 1}^{k^2 } {\frac{{r_2 (j)}}{j}}
$$ and use the def. of Sierpiński's constant with $n=k^2$.
